# Enable variable value in Timeline

Tags: angular, typescript

I developed a timeline that activates according to clicks and changes colors.

My problem is that I can't activate the timeline with the value of the variable value.

Example: My variable value = 4, would enable timeline with number 4, if value = 3 enabled timeline number 3 ....

Does anyone know how I can apply this?

Thanks

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqmcds?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <div id="connection" [class]="classOfConnection()" ></div>   
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let priority of priorities" [class]="classOfPriority(priority.id)" 
      (click)="onClick(priority.id)">{{ priority.id }}</li>    
  </ul>  
</div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
value = 4;

  priorities = [
    { id: 4, text: 'Low', isComplete: true},
    { id: 3, text: 'Mid Low', isComplete: false},
    { id: 2, text: 'Mid', isComplete: false},
    { id: 1, text: 'High', isComplete: false},
  ];


  onClick(id: number) {
    const priority = this.priorities.find(p => p.id === id);
    priority.isComplete = !priority.isComplete;
    if (priority.isComplete) {
      this.priorities.filter(p => p !== priority).forEach(p => p.isComplete = false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate , are you asking like when click over an element you want to change it's color.

Comment: What do you mean by activating the timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add methods for that:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.setInitialStateOfProgress(4);
}

setInitialStateOfProgress(initialState) {
  this.priorities.forEach(priority => {
    priority.isComplete = priority.id === initialState
  })
}
```

You can then call `setInitialStateOfProgress` with an initial state value and that would be set as the initial state of the timeline.

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Code Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-progress-with-custom-initial-state?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: It works ! But there is another way to accomplish this without having to use ngOnInit, because there are cases that don't work because ngOnInit runs only once. But thank you so much for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

If I got the problem correctly, you want to activate the timeline with a value (Ex:1,2,3,4) at the beginning.

You can do this by calling the onClick(i) in the constructor.

```
constructor(){
  this.onClick(1);
}
```

If you call onClick(4) it will deactivate the timeline.